# Wordpress: Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content for style.css of theme

Tags: wordpress, performance, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I am using Twenty Seventeen theme and trying to achieve a good score on Google Page Speed test. I am facing an issue of "**Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold**" and "**Leverage browser caching**" of style.css of Twenty Seventeen theme.

I tried to eliminate this with the .htaccess file, but still getting the same issue.

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
    # WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    # END WordPress
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
    ExpiresByType image/jpg A2592000
    ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon A2592000
    ExpiresByType text/css A86400
    ExpiresByType text/javascript A86400
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A2592000
    #
    <FilesMatch "\.(gif¦jpe?g¦png¦ico¦css¦js¦swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
    </FilesMatch>
```

I don't want to use any optimization plugins or cache plugins.

To fix "**Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold**" for the js files, I added a code to the function.php file.

Here is the code:

```
  function defer_parsing_of_js ( $url ) {
        if ( FALSE === strpos( $url, '.js' ) ) return $url;   
        if ( strpos( $url, 'jquery.js' ) ) return $url;
        return "$url' async defer='defer";
    }
    add_filter( 'clean_url', 'defer_parsing_of_js', 11, 1 );
```

Can anyone suggest me to get this fixed without using plugin?

Comment: Please check this url: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162150/can-i-add-styles-to-footer-with-wp-styles-add-data

Comment: Thanks for your response. I somehow managed to fix the speed.

Comment: I am facing another issue that when I remove the header image of the theme as i don't need that header banner image, then speed lower down by 15%. I don't know why this is happening. I am removing the image from the theme options but removing image is affecting the site speed. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
ExpiresByType image/x-icon A2592000
ExpiresByType text/css A86400
ExpiresByType text/javascript A86400
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A2592000
#
```

Comment: I am already using this in my .htaccess file. I added my .htaccess content in my post above.